# Why does removeChild still has image added from previous addChild?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Sorry that it was hard to phrase the question. 
But i am encountering a problem, 
What i am trying to do:

1.) I have a loop that add different bitmap images to sprites,

2.) Each sprites when clicked, it traces the index

3.) The index add that image again as a duplicate

4.) When the image is clicked again, it removeChild(the duplicate).

But the problem is when a second image is clicked(step 2,3) it adds child (supposively it should be only the child clicked that is added), but it adds the old images underneath the image clicked.

So if its the first image, it is just the image, when its second image clicked, even it has removedChild from last image, the new image added has the old image added underneath it. 
Not sure why it does that.

Anyone has any idea? the code are very long, not sure if its a simple problem that can be identify without seeing the code.

Thanks for your time and help!

Edit:
Code:

```
private var image:Array = new Array;
function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {

                loadedArray.push(e.target.content as Bitmap);




        for(var i:int = 0; i < loadedArray.length; i++){
                var currentY1:int = 200;


                 e.currentTarget.loader.content.height =200;
                 e.currentTarget.loader.content.y += currentY1;
                 image[i] = new Sprite();
                 image[i].addChild(loadedArray[i]);
                 image[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscene);
                 image.mouseChildren = true;    // ignore children mouseEvents
                 image.mouseEnabled = true;      // enable mouse on the object - normally set to true by default
                 image.useHandCursor = true;     // add hand cursor on mouse over
                 image.buttonMode = true; 




                 _contentHolder.addChild(image[i]);

                    }
function gotoscene(e: MouseEvent):void{


       index = image.indexOf(e.target);
       trace(index);


        blackBox.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        blackBox.graphics.drawRect( -1, -1, stage.width, stage.height);
        blackBox.alpha = 0.7;
        addChild(blackBox);




        var originalBitmap : BitmapData = loadedArray[index].bitmapData;
        var duplicate:Bitmap = new Bitmap(originalBitmap);
        duplicate.y = 100;
        duplicate.width = stage.width;
        duplicate.height = (stage.width/originalBitmap.width)*originalBitmap.height;

        _contentHolder1.addChild(duplicate);


        addChild(_contentHolder1);


        blackBox.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscene1);
        _contentHolder1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoscene1);




           }

            public function gotoscene1(e:MouseEvent):void{

            removeChild(blackBox);
            removeChild(_contentHolder1);



            }
```

Edit:
add image with index 0

add image with index 0
add image with index 1

add image with index 0
add image with index 1
add image with index 2

Comment: Hey again Clarklight :) You should post some code, as there is no clue what you're doing.. As you say it it works correct - you add bitmap. Then add some duplicate. You remove the duplicate, and the first bitmap remains.. But again - there's nothing that can be done without code.

Comment: Hi Andrey!! :) I must say thanks so much for spending time to looking at my question again!! I edited my question and placed the code in there. I always thought when i removedChild then the image is removed, but for some reason, when i addChild again the previous image is still there....

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting it here as it's long and not enough for a comment.

I think the reason for that problem is because you loop through `loadedArray` **every time an image is loaded**. You load one image - you add it, push it to loadedArray. Load second image, push it to array, **loop through it**, and there are `image1` and `image2`. So **again** you add image1, and the newly loaded image3. Third time - loop through all - you add first element (`image1`), second (`image2`), then third.. So you are making copies of all loaded images every time you get some image loaded.

So if you have 5 images to load, the first one will be added 5 times.

You have two choices - either to be sure that you call this loop when **all** the images are loaded; or second - to not use the loop at all. Why you use it, for setting position? If so - make a class variable that you increase with 200 each time there is a new image. Otherwise - I don't know what's the meaning and I think that there's the problem..

Comment: you mentioned about calling this loop when all the images are loaded, i am not sure what do you mean by that tho, because when i click the images, all of them are loaded already and are already displaying on stage, is that what you mean? When i click an image i am only making duplicate of the image that has loaded.

Comment: Check your code, it's not about when you click. All that code is within `onImageLoaded`, which means that it's called **every time an image gets loaded from loader**. Each time you loop through **all loaded images** and add them. Which you should do only once, not let's say 5 times (if you have 5 images to load), right? You don't want image1 to be displayed 5 times, you want it a single time. What's the loop for?

Comment: You are talking about this line image[i].addChild(loadedArray[i]);??  Because loadedArray.push(e.target.content as Bitmap); isnt inside the loop. But at the moment it isnt adding everything from before tho, it is only added the previous image "clicked", so if i clicked image 3 and i removeChild and click image 3 again, it is displaying 2 image 3 but not image 1 nor 2, only two image 3 one overlapping another.

Comment: Not just the image readded back, also the blackbox(which is just some graphic) added, it also added again when the addChild added next. I removed both of them, but when i add the next Child, the image and blackbox also added again with the new ones

Comment: The loop man :) Don't think about clicking, check out the loop! Add this line right after the `for` statement (at the first line of the loop): `trace ('add image with index', i);`. You will see how much times you are adding the images..

Comment: Just did that, i think i am getting what you mean, i put the trace result in the question above in Edit, it adds image 0 then add 0,1 then it adds 0,1,2

Comment: See, image 0 is added (duplicated) multiple times. So even if you remove it, some old replica is behind it and stays like nothing happens. You should remove that loop - why you need it at all? Edit: You get the idea that `onImageLoaded` is called **every** time **any** image gets loaded, right? It's not called once when all images get loaded..

Comment: Hi, i know that the onImageLoaded is called every time any image gets loaded, but i didnt know that it stacks up, i thought it just loops and add the second and then third image so on, cos of the i++ from the for loop, and do i not need the loop? Because i need to loop it to get all the images right? I only thought i need the for loop for this line image[i].addChild(loadedArray[i]);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54418/discussion-between-andrey-popov-and-clarklight).

Comment: I resolved the problem, its to do with Garbage collection, have to nullify it in order to totally removeChild, otherwise it hasnt been collected, so the last child stuck onto the addChild.

Comment: Glad that works. You should close the question somehow, either accepting any answer or writing your own. Cheers!